# VMware version required for shared-nothing vMotion

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmotion

I'm wondering which is the minimal version I would need regarding these points :
1. Have 2 ESXi hosts, datastore located directly in the server (not on a SAN)
2. Would like to be able to use vMotion to transfer VMs to the 2nd server

So my questions are :
1. Can I use vMotion with these server settings, or do I really need a SAN?
2. Minimal version I need to purchase is vSphere Essential Plus (around 4500$ US) or I can purchase another cheaper version(s) that include vMotion?

ESXi-1 is main production server, ESXi-2 is mostly a backup server in case hardware problem would occur on ESXi-1.  A Yes/No, use "that" VmWare software reply would be enough for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](http://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

Comment: Meh, it's about allowed technical capabilities of the different versions, for a specific technical goal, not "help me keep my licensing valid." A question about "How do I cluster Windows Web Edition", would likewise be licensing-related, but not a licensing question as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the VMware Essentials Plus package or greater to leverage vMotion capabilities.

This is outlined in the [**VMware Editions comparison table**](http://www.vmware.com/products/datacenter-virtualization/vsphere/compare-kits.html).

With two hosts and no SAN, you can still perform a [*"shared-nothing" vMotion*](http://www.vmware.com/files/pdf/techpaper/VMware-vSphere51-vMotion-Perf.pdf) between the hosts, but it's only for a scheduled move. If a system fails completely, the VMs residing on the local storage would go with it. Adding shared storage would help.

Comment: Kindly appreciate, that's what I was thinking, but wasn't really sure if I was right in my understandings.

Comment: In addition, the vSphere Essentials Plus kit includes the vSphere Storage Appliance which will allow you to create a virtual iSCSI SAN from the local storage on your hosts. It essentially creates a "network raid" from the local storage of each host, allowing you some degree of HA (albeit manually) and removes the single point of failure that local storage presents. - http://www.vmware.com/products/datacenter-virtualization/vsphere/vsphere-storage-appliance/faqs.html